# python is not printing every combination of 3 letters and is missing a lot

Tags: python, combinations

this python code isnt printing every combination of 3 letters, and is missing a lot of them.
the code i copyed is

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

alphabets = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

for (a,b,c) in combinations_with_replacement(alphabets, 3):
    print(a+b+c)
```

it is missing a few combinations, like the combination "cas"
and sorry if i dont respond in 5 seconds

Comment: It has `acs` which is the same as `cas`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all combinations by using `product`:

```
import itertools
...
for (a, b, c) in itertools.product(alphabets, repeat=3):
    print(a+b+c)

# Output:
# aaa
# aab
# aac
# aad
# aae
# ...
```

If you don't need `aaa` or `bbb`, you can use `permutations`:

```
import itertools
...
for (a, b, c) in itertools.permutations(alphabets, 3):
    print(a+b+c)

# Output:
# abc
# abd
# abe
# abf
# ...
# azw
# azx
# azy
# bac
# bad
# bae
# ...
```

`combinations_with_replacement` won't repeat combinations, i.e., if you already printed `abc`, you won't see `cba`.

See also https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import product
from string import ascii_lowercase
keywords = [''.join(i) for i in product(ascii_lowercase, repeat = 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to do `permutations` instead of `combinations_with_replacement`.

Example:

```
from itertools import permutations

alphabets = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

for (a,b,c) in permutations(alphabets, 3):
    print(a+b+c)
```

Comment: hey, 'baa' is missing in your results

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that subsets with different arrangement of elements are considered as the same. So `(aba)` and `(baa)` are the same.

To prevent this, you can simply use three embedded for loops:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

alphabets = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
             'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

for first in alphabets:
    for second in alphabets:
        for third in alphabets:
            print(first+second+third)
```

Comment: You can use `itertools.product(alphabets)` for this.

Answer (score 0):

Complete newbie to this, but it looks like what you're really looking for is product() rather than combinations_with_replacement()

Try this:

```
from itertools import product

for _ in product(alphabets, repeat = 3):
   print("".join(_))
```